# JNA with Libvirt c code. What did i do wrong?

Tags: java, jna, libvirt

I'm new to JNA and am trying to get a storage info with `libvirt` c and JNA.

There are two libvirt c functions, `virConnectListAllStoragePools()` and `virStoragePoolGetInfo()`, as shown below.

```
    /**
     * virConnectListAllStoragePools:
     * @conn: Pointer to the hypervisor connection.
     * @pools: Pointer to a variable to store the array containing storage pool
     *         objects or NULL if the list is not required (just returns number
     *         of pools).
     * @flags: bitwise-OR of virConnectListAllStoragePoolsFlags.
     *
     * Collect the list of storage pools, and allocate an array to store those
     * objects. This API solves the race inherent between
     * virConnectListStoragePools and virConnectListDefinedStoragePools.
     *
     * Normally, all storage pools are returned; however, @flags can be used to
     * filter the results for a smaller list of targeted pools.  The valid
     * flags are divided into groups, where each group contains bits that
     * describe mutually exclusive attributes of a pool, and where all bits
     * within a group describe all possible pools.
     *
     * The first group of @flags is VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_ACTIVE (online)
     * and VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_INACTIVE (offline) to filter the pools
     * by state.
     *
     * The second group of @flags is VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_PERSITENT
     * (defined) and VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_TRANSIENT (running but not
     * defined), to filter the pools by whether they have persistent config or not.
     *
     * The third group of @flags is VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_AUTOSTART
     * and VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_NO_AUTOSTART, to filter the pools by
     * whether they are marked as autostart or not.
     *
     * The last group of @flags is provided to filter the pools by the types,
     * the flags include:
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_DIR
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_FS
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_NETFS
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_LOGICAL
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_DISK
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_ISCSI
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_SCSI
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_MPATH
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_RBD
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_SHEEPDOG
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_GLUSTER
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_ZFS
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_VSTORAGE
     * VIR_CONNECT_LIST_STORAGE_POOLS_ISCSI_DIRECT
     *
     * Returns the number of storage pools found or -1 and sets @pools to
     * NULL in case of error.  On success, the array stored into @pools is
     * guaranteed to have an extra allocated element set to NULL but not included
     * in the return count, to make iteration easier.  The caller is responsible
     * for calling virStoragePoolFree() on each array element, then calling
     * free() on @pools.
     */
    int
    virConnectListAllStoragePools(virConnectPtr conn,
                                  virStoragePoolPtr **pools,
                                  unsigned int flags)        
    {
    //logic about set pool pointer to parameter '**pools' and return number of pools.
    }

    /**
     * virStoragePoolGetInfo:
     * @pool: pointer to storage pool
     * @info: pointer at which to store info
     *
     * Get volatile information about the storage pool
     * such as free space / usage summary
     *
     * Returns 0 on success, or -1 on failure.
     */
    int
    virStoragePoolGetInfo(virStoragePoolPtr pool,
                          virStoragePoolInfoPtr info)
    {
    // logic about set pool info to parameter 'info'.
    }
```

My java code with JNA is:.

1) StoragePoolPointer.java

```
    import com.sun.jna.PointerType;
    public class StoragePoolPointer extends PointerType {}
```

2) virStoragePoolInfo

```
    public class virStoragePoolInfo extends Struture {
       public int state;
       public long capacity;
       public long allocation;
       public long available;
       private static final List<String> filedls = Arrays.asList("state", "capacity", "allocation", "available");

       protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
          return fields;
       }
    }
```

3) Libvirt.java interface

```
    public interface Libvirt extends Library {
       int virConnectListAllStoragePools(ConnectionPoinet VCP, StoragePoolPointer[] pPointers, int flag);

       int virStoragePoolGetInfo(StoragePoolPointer poolPointer, virStoragePoolInfo info);
    }
```

4) jna test code

```
    public void listAllStoragePools(ConnectionPointer VCP) {
       Libvirt libvirt = (Libvirt) Native.loadLibrary("virt", Libvirt.class);

       StoragePoolPointer[] pPointerArr = new StoragePoolPointer[10];
       int result = livirt.virConnectListAllStoragePools(VCP, pPointerArr, 64);
       // result is fine. i get storage pool count. and also i get StoragePoolPointer object inside array.

       virStoragePoolInfo poolInfo = new virStoragePoolInfo(); 
       libvirt.virStoragePoolGetInfo(pPointerArr[0], poolInfo);
       // when i call libvirt.virStoragePoolGetInfo(). i get a error msg like this. 'libvirt: Storage Driver error : invalid storage pool pointer in virStoragePoolGetInfo.
       //error msg : org.libvirt.LibvirtException: invalid storage pool pointer in virStoragePoolGetInfo.
    }
```

I think i made wrong interface method `virConnectListAllStoragePools()` and I am passing the wrong parameter for 'virStoragePoolPtr **pools'.

Answer (score 0):

Native arrays are laid out in contiguous memory.  In this case, `virStoragePoolPtr **pools` is a single pointer to the *beginning* of the array; and C uses its knowledge of pointer size to use offsets to find the remaining elements.

JNA does not translate (most) Java arrays to this native layout.  When it does so, it uses clearly defined sizes, such as for primitive arrays like `int[]` or for arrays of `Structure` that JNA can calculate the size for, and allocate with its `toArray` method.

You have defined a Java-side array here:

```
StoragePoolPointer[] pPointerArr = new StoragePoolPointer[10];
```

But you have not allocated any Java objects to fill the array with, so it's simply an array of `null`s.  Further, even if you did fill the array by iterating and setting `pPointerArr[i] = new StoragePoolPointer()` you would have non-contiguous native memory attached to those pointers.

There are (at least) two approaches to solving this.  One is directly allocating the native memory using JNA's `Memory` class, like this:

```
pPointerArr = new Memory(10 * Native.POINTER_SIZE);
```

After the method call to `virConnectListAllStoragePools()`, you'd have the pointers in this buffer and could iterate, e.g., `Pointer p = pPointerArr.share(i * Native.POINTER_SIZE)` would be each pointer as you incremented `i`.

Alternately, you could define a `Structure` containing a pointer, like this:

```
@FieldOrder({ "storagePool" })
public class StoragePoolPointer extends Structure {
    public Pointer storagePool;
}
```

Then you could get both the Java array convenience *and* contiguous native memory with:

```
StoragePoolPointer[] pPointerArr = 
    (StoragePoolPointer[]) new StoragePoolPointer().toArray(10);
```

After populating the arrays, `pPointerArr[i].storagePool` would be the `i`th pointer.

Assuming the `10` you are using is just a test placeholder, the standard JNA idiom in this situation is to call `virConnectListAllStoragePools()` once with a null pointer to get the number of elements to use, then allocate the memory as I've described above and call it a second time with the properly sized buffer (or array of Structures backed by a buffer).